# Unfolding this C++ method

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand a code in `C++`. I have found this loop:

```
for (i = 1, prev = fcu->bezt, bezt = fcu->bezt + 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++, prev = bezt++) {
   // do something
```

This loop has multiple declarations. Never saw that before.

Is this equivalent to

```
for (i = 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++) {
  prev = fcu->bezt;
  bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;

  // do something

  prev = bezt++

}
```

thanks

Comment: No. Look at when the assignments occur and how often.

Comment: look up the comma operator.

Comment: `i = 1, prev = fcu->bezt, bezt = fcu->bezt + 1` aren't declarations, it's bad practice.

Comment: Your question whether the two snippets are equivalent could easily be answered by yourself. Extract a minimal example (it's required anyway, making your question off-topic) and try it yourself.

Comment: You are wrong because I don't know C++ and this code is insane. Thanks for down voting.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In languages with UB and buggy compilers, "try it and see" isn't as useful as you'd like.

Comment: Hmmm, I am wrong because you don't know C++? That doesn't make any sense to me. Anyhow, if you don't know C++, you should read a tutororial, asking Questions on SO is not a replacement for that. Lastly, you sound as if you feel the downvote was not deserved, but it "does not show any research effort" and it "is unclear" because there isn't even complete code.

Comment: There is no tutorial explaining how to interpret a piece of code. You should be more friendly. SO is a place where people help other people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually more like:

```
{
    i = 1;
    prev = fcu->bezt;
    bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;
    while (i < fcu->totvert)
    {
        // do something

        i++;
        prev = bezt++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I think its equal with:

```
prev = fcu->bezt;
bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;
for (i = 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++) {

  // do something

  prev = bezt++

}
```

The columns in `for` are `for(initialization; condition; increment)`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly - it's equivalent to:

```
prev = fcu->bezt;
bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;
for (i = 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++) {
    // do something
    prev = bezt++
}
```

Everything before the first semi-colon is the initializer list which only runs once before looping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have accepted the answer of someone that answered the same thing one minute before you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries, @SpaceDog!

Answer (score 1):

You two loops are not equivalent.  A for loop has the syntax

```
for ( declaration(optional) ; condition(optional) ; increment(optional) )
```

Where the `declaration` is only ran when the loop is first entered, the `condition` is ran at the beginning of each loop and the `increment` is ran at the end of each iteration.  If you were to break it up the loops most equivalent would be

```
prev = fcu->bezt;
bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;
for (i = 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++) {

  // do something

  prev = bezt++

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have accepted the answer of someone that answered the same thing one minute before you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SpaceDog No problem.  The accept is to give to whoever you feel like.

Answer (score 1):

I c++ the for loop is defined as follow:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
{ 
   statement(s);
}
```

I think the code can be rewtritten int this way:

```
prev = fcu->bezt;
bezt = fcu->bezt + 1;

for (i = 1; i < fcu->totvert; i++) {
  // do something

  prev = bezt++

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have accepted the answer of someone that answered the same thing four minutes before you. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. The for loop

```
for (init; condition ; increment ) { body; }
```

is equivalent to

```
init;
while(condition) {
    body;
    increment;
}
```

In the loop you wrote, you put the init part consisting of several statements split by "," partly in the body that gets executed for each iteration (but it gets executed only once).